# How to detect the view mode (PersonalizationScope) of a SharePoint WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

How do I check programmatically whether a web part is displayed in the shared resp. in personal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PersonalizationScope can be accessed like this:

```
public class MyWebPart: WebPart 
{
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (WebPartManager.Personalization.Scope == PersonalizationScope.Shared)
    {
      // Do something
    }
  } 
}
```